# Django multiple primary keys for table error

Tags: python, django, heroku, django-import-export

My Django application is working just fine on localhost, but when I try to push it to Heroku I get the following error:

remote: django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: multiple primary keys for table "Clientes_productlist" are not allowed

My `models.py` file is:

```
class ProductList(models.Model):
    id_new = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    sku = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    client = models.ForeignKey(get_user_model(), on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    storage = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    cost_price = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    sell_price = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    ncm = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    inventory = models.IntegerField(null=True)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (('sku', 'client'),)
```

I am using django-import-export package as well. Therefore, my `resources.py` is:

```
class ProductListResource(resources.ModelResource):

    class Meta:
        model = ProductList
        skip_unchanged = True
        report_skipped = True
        exclude = ('id',)
        import_id_fields = ('sku', 'client',)
        fields = ('sku', 'client', 'name', 'description', 'storage', 'cost_price', 'sell_price', 'ncm', 'inventory',)
```

What is causing that error and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fix that, you need to delete all the migration files in `migrations` folder of the app in which `ProductList` model exists, except for `__init__.py` file and run `./manage.py makemigrations` to generate new migrations. Then commit those migrations and push them to Heroku.

Comment: Great, dude! Thanks again for the help!

Comment: After that I am getting this error now: column Clientes_productlist.id_new does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT "Clientes_productlist"."id_new", "Clientes_productlis... Do you have any clue on this?

Comment: i am assuming Clientes has FK to ProductList. So it had a migration which was related to/dependent on ProductList migrations. As ProductList migrations were created later, thus the problem occured. Maybe its best if you delete all the migrations files from the project (except for `__init__.py` files inside migration directory), and run `makemigrations` and commit them. also reset DB in heroku before committing the migrations and running them in heroku. Maybe this document will help to reset db: https://gist.github.com/zulhfreelancer/ea140d8ef9292fa9165e

Comment: Now I have this error when I try to access any page: relation "django_session" does not exist
LINE 1: ...ession_data", "django_session"."expire_date" FROM "django_se...

Comment: Nevermind, I just deleted the entire database in Heroku and pushed back. Now everything is fine!